# Зачем в public RotationAxes axes нужен RotationAxes || C#

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
﻿public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour 
    {
      public enum RotationAxes
           {
              MouseXAndY = 0,  
              MouseX = 1,
              MouseY = 2 ﻿  
           }
    {
 public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
...
```

Зачем в public RotationAxes axes нужен RotationAxes?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Вы в курсе про `enum` вообще, как он описывается и применяется?

Comment: Сам понимаю, но не в документации не в статьях не могу найти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дизайн языка такой. Чтобы отличить например переменную, поле или свойство MouseX от значения перечисления RotationAxes.MouseX.

Представьте себе ситуацию

```cs
public enum RotationAxes
{
    MouseXAndY = 0,  
    MouseX = 1,
    MouseY = 2 ﻿  
}

﻿public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private RotationAxes MouseXAndY = (RotationAxes)1;

    public RotationAxes axes = MouseXAndY;
}
```

Этот код скомпилируется, но только будет работать неправильно. Значение `axes` будет на самом деле `MouseX`. Поэтому, чтобы ничего не перепутать название перечисления указывается явно, и только потом его элемент.